# Best way to have multinode elastic on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

It's decided to have elastic on AWS, not OpenSearch, since there are some differences and in the future we can have problems while developing things on local on elastic and deploying to live on opensearch. It's decided to use EC2 instance for one elastic node.
We need to implement a feed(like in FB) for our primary resource - Company. A company can have thousands of posts. Our potential audience are people from America, Europe and Asia. So there should be 3 clusters - one per continent (replicas). Can someone tell me the best way to have elastic on 3 continents and pay as less as possible, because we are startup without any investment. I think the best way to have 3 powerful EC2 instances - one per continent. Or maybe use some 3rd party cloud solution for storing elastic server?

I also checked elastic cloud service on AWS and its very expensive. For $1 I'll have only 1000 units. That means, if I have 1000 companies in my app(each company will pay about $5) and each company have 1000 posts, I'll pay $1.000.000 to AWS :D

For now I decided to write a driver to write posts into PostgreSQL, but this will not work in the future, I need to migrate to ES as soon as possible

Comment: I think you likely misunderstood the AWS offering's price and are also looking at their "serverless" option. If you care about high availability, the guidance from elastic is a minimum of 3 instances per region/cluster.

Comment: Their article on discussing cluster sizes can be found here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/high-availability-cluster-small-clusters.html